# Item of type 'MappingData' can not be saved. Unable to connect to 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' using authentication type 'Windows'

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

we are using SDL Web 8.5 while updating publication properties we are not able to save the publication and getting below error

```
Item of type 'MappingData' can not be saved. Unable to connect to 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' using authentication type 'Windows'.
The logon attempt failed
Component: Tridion.TopologyManager.Service
Errorcode: 11
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
StackTrace Information Details:
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.ContentManagerValidator.ThrowConnectionProblemsException[T](CmEnvironmentData cmEnvironment, String resourceName, Exception innerException)
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.ContentManagerValidator.AssertPublicationExistAndUrlValid(MappingData mapping, String mappingUrl)
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.ContentManagerValidator.OnUpdating(TopologyItemData item, TtmOperationContext context)
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.CrossSystemBusinessLogicRegistry.OnUpdating(TopologyItemData item, TtmOperationContext context)
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.TopologyItem`1.Update(T delta, TtmOperationContext context)
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.TopologyItemController`1.Update(String key, T entity)
    at Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.TopologyItemController`1.Patch(String key, T entity)
    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

The MTS user is already there in CMS and has system administrator rights

Comment: Are you sure that Topology Manager is using the MTS user to connect? What do you see if you run the `Get-TtmCmEnvironment` PowerShell commandlet? Does the user identified in the **CoreServiceCredentials** attributed definitely have access to the Content Manager? Could the password have changed?

Comment: what authentication type are you using for topology manager. Most times its anonymous or OAuth.

Answer (score 4):

For MTSUser **is_predefined** field of Trustees table was set to 0 after setting it to 1 the issue get resolved

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution. Hopefully someone (from SDL or otherwise) can shed some light on why this is important/needed.

Comment: I guess it’s related to the new security model in SDL Web 8.5: accounts now get their (sysadmin) privileges through group memberships. Your account gets sysadmin privileges if you are member of the System Administrators Group. The built-in “MTSUser” account is not member of this Group, but an exception is made for predefined accounts.

Comment: That's good to know, Rick. Thanks for taking the time to improve my understanding :)