# Item of type 'MappingData' cannot be saved with user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: core-service, web8.5, topology-manager

I have the same issue as stated here: [Item of type 'MappingData' can not be saved. Unable to connect to 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' using authentication type 'Windows'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19682/item-of-type-mappingdata-can-not-be-saved-unable-to-connect-to-net-tcp-loc) and here https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=Item-of-type-MappingData-cannot-be-saved. But for me the solutions do not work.

So my impersonation user is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE:

[image]

I also have this user in my TRUSTEE table :

[image]

I get the same error when I run the Add-TtmMapping command via PowerShell

When I check Event Viewer I also see every 10 seconds the following error, related to the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account

[image]

Is there maybe an issue that NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE cannot be used as a valid impersonation user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following steps to fix your issue:

1. To ensure currently logged in user Member of **Topology Manager Administrators** group to read and edit Topology Manager environments configuration.
2. Run this PowerShell cmdlet **Get-TtmCmEnvironment** to verify CMS URL and Credentials are configured correctly to your environments details.

**Example:**

```
    PS C:\Users\vagrant> Get-TtmCmEnvironment

    CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://localhost:2660
    WebsiteRootUrl         : http://VAGRANT-2016:80
    CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"VAGRANT-2016\MTSUser", "Password":"********"
    Id                     : Tridioncm_localhost
    ExtensionProperties    : {}
```

3. Double check MTSUser exist in Content Manager Trustees table, It uses the Core Service URL and credentials specified in above CmEnvironment entity (in Topology Manager). The credentials should be of an existing, enabled User account (with sysadmin privileges)
4. Double check CMS URL and User Credentials are configured correctly to your environment specific, Need to update using this PowerShell cmdlets.

`Set-TtmCmEnvironment -AuthenticationType Windows -UserName "VAGRANT-2016\MTSUser" -Password "xxxx" -WebsiteRootUrl http://VAGRANT-2016:80`

5. In your CME server System Environment variables ensure your envivironemnt variable **TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID** matches your TtmCmEnvironmentId, eg: Tridioncm_localhost
6. If you have a scale-out CME / Publisher servers environment step 1 to 5 should be same on all the servers.

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Velmurugan, I think you pointed out the issue. As User account for the CoreService the MTSUser is defined, while it tries to connect as NETWORK SERVICE. When I try to change the user to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, it gives the same error. So I think the other option is to Add the MTSUser as impersonation user, is that correct?

Comment: AFAIK, Not required to add MTSUser as impersonation user in SDL Console.

Comment: NOW IT WORKS! I was confused because the error in Event Viewer was about the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user. But when I readded the MTSUser as Admin I was able to add the mapping. Do you know where the error comes from?

Comment: Good to know it works now :-), Looks like from your batch service?

Comment: Also the Topology Manager was throwing that error (6 lines below in the Event Viewer screenshot). But also of the NETWORK SERVICE account. So not sure why adding the MTSUser as admin fixed this issue. But I'll accept your answer because it is great information to debug the issue.